# ¿como puedo obtener un dato especifico en un mapa en java?

Tags: java, spring-tool-suite

hola como puedo tomar un valor especifico dentro de un mapa ??
por medio de un set ??

```
            do {
                Student s = new Student();

                s.setListName(numerolista2);
                System.out.println("ingrese su nombre:");
                String name = sc.nextLine();
                s.setName(name);
                System.out.println("calificacion");

                int grade = sc.nextInt();
                s.setGrade(grade);
                sc.nextLine();
                map.put(numerolista2, s);

                System.out.println("deseas calificar mas alumnos: ");
                repetir = sc.nextInt();
                sc.nextLine();

            } while (repetir == 1);

            break;

        }
```

Comment: El código provisto no se relaciona con la pregunta que haces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para obtener el valor de un mapa de java debes usar el método get(key), debes pasarle como parámetro la key que usaste para almacenar el valor. En esta página puedes ver [la documentación de AbstractMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.html)

Comment: muchas gracias ya me quedo y gracias por la pagina